# NextJS Get host in _document.js or _app.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I have a NextJs website that runs on different hostnames. And when the app starts I need to get data from an API based on the url the NextJS runs on.

So for example my NextJS runs on `websiteA.com` and `websiteB.com`
And when somebody visits the website I need to request data from an API that returns for example a specific logo, or website title for each url.

So for `websiteA.com` I would request `http://api.com/websitedata?url=websiteA` and it would return:

```
{
   name: "MyWebsite",
   logo: "/logo1.png"
}
```

So for `websiteB.com` I would request `http://api.com/websitedata?url=websiteB` and it would return:

```
{
   name: "TheirWebsite",
   logo: "/logo2.png"
}
```

Now I thought about running a `GetInitialProps` on document and that partly works. Because sometimes the `context.res` is null and sometimes it does contain the hostname.

Anybody have an idea how I can reliable do an api request based on the hostname / url?

```
export default function Document() {
  return (
        <Html lang="en">
          <Head />
          <body>
            <Main />
            <NextScript />
          </body>
        </Html>
  );
}
```

```
Document.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const {req, query, res, asPath, pathname} = context.ctx;
  //Here req is sometimes undefined and sometimes filled.
};
```

Comment: Have you looked into creating env variables then accessing them in your program? This way, you could set an env variable (lets say its called hostUrl) as whatever, then call it through process.env['hostUrl'] in your next app.

Comment: If you're on Vercel, you can use the [system env variables](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables#system-environment-variables) - specifically `VERCEL_URL` on the server and `NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL` on the client. Why can't you use `http://api.com/websitedata?website=window.location.hostname`

Comment: @SeanW window doesn't work server side as there is no Window.

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck with similar issue. However, I have found some temporary solution for rendering logo and title. Instead of requesting, you should render it statically using  in _document.js

```
<script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `let linkElement = document.createElement('link');
          linkElement.rel = 'icon';
          const path = window.location.pathname;
          linkElement.href = path.toLowerCase().includes("name in URL") ? 'staticPathForLogo' : 'staticPathForLogo2';
          document.head.appendChild(linkElement);`,
        }}
/>
```

same way you can go for title too.

May be you can add request in this too instead of static rendering. (I haven't tested it using data from request but have used above code and was working as expected)